# Sample size cutoff for agreement coefficients

Tags: sampling, binomial-distribution, statistical-power, reliability, agreement-statistics

New poster here. Would love some help thinking through this.

Suppose I am observing individuals in public space, and I am recording the number of occurrences of a target behavior (e.g., looking at a cell phone, taking a drink from a water fountain) that occur within the observation window (e.g., 1 hr). I do this by splitting the 1-hr observation into 60 1-min intervals, for which I mark the behavior as either present (i.e., it happened at least once) or absent (i.e., it didn't happen at all) during each interval.

Let's say a secondary independent observer is also recording the target behavior during this time, and after the observation period is over we compare our agreement (e.g., divide the number of intervals with agreeement by the total number of intervals [or some comparable method]) to get some kind of agreement coefficient (e.g., 1.0 = perfect agreement).

Suppose we repeat this multiple times a day, for multiple days or weeks.

My question is, how could we empirically determine the minimum number of observations that the secondary observer would need to be present/collecting data and still be confident that our reliability estimates are valid (assuming agreement is good/acceptable).

Said another way, how can we determine the minimum proportion of observations that require a second observer to be reasonably confident that the aforementioned agreement coefficients are reliable (e.g., are there differences in reliability if the secondary observer is there for 33% of observations vs. 75%?).
**What are some options for identifying this criterion/cutoff?**

Thanks for your time!

Comment: The larger your sample, the more reliability there will be of your measures. The amount it increases depends on how reliable the measures are. Best thing to do is to make up some numbers and run a simulation.

Comment: I'm wondering if it makes sense to identify this minimum value by finding the inverse of the cumulative binomial distribution across a number of observations (e.g., 1 to 100). If so, would it be reasonable to set the alpha level as the known proportion of observations with excellent agreement (e.g., agreement coefficient >= .9, etc)?